# Remove spaces from character string in PostgreSQL data request

Tags: r, postgresql

I am trying to use a flexible string to call data from an SWL database, and therefore use the `paste()` function to create a text string, then insert that string into another `paste()` function that is inserted into a `dbGetQuery()` function. When I create the string, I don't see any spaces before or after the characters. However, when I insert it into the `dbGetQuery()` function it adds spaces before and after. This returns a blank table, whereas when I manually enter the characters it gives me a table with values. How can I eliminate the spaces before and after?

code:

```
month<-seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-01"),by="1 month")
months<-format(month,format="%b%y")
spread<-paste(months[1],months[2],sep="/")
request<-paste("SELECT data FROM database where strip='",spread,"';")
data<-dbGetQuery(con,request)
```

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `?paste` you'll see that the `sep` argument default is a single blank space. That argument can be changed. The documentation also references the convenience function `paste0`.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. `paste(months[1],months[2],sep="/")` yields "Jan17/Feb17". That is fine. When I run `paste("SELECT data FROM database where strip='",spread,"';)` it returns the text "SELECT data FROM database where strip=' Jan17/Feb17 ';". The space in front of Jan and behind 17 is the issue. `paste0(months[1,2],collapse="/")` does not address this.

Comment: You were quite clear! :) You're confused, I think, about the difference between `sep` and `collapse`. Experiment a little bit with my suggestions and I think you'll figure it out rather quickly.

Comment: ...also, I think probably there are some typos in the code in your question, namely some unclosed quotes and/or parens when you create `request`.

Comment: `spread<-paste0(months[1:2],collapse="/")`
`paste("example'",spread,"'")`
"example' Jan-17/Feb-17 '"
`spread1<-paste(months[1],months[2],sep="/")`
`paste("example'",spread1,"'")`
"example' Jan-17/Feb-17 '"
`spread2<-paste(months[1:2],collapse="/")`
`paste("example'",spread2,"'")`
"example' Jan-17/Feb-17 '"

Comment: I see you posting comments and deleting them, so maybe you're still confused here. Try `paste("SELECT data FROM database where strip='",spread,"';",sep = "")`

Comment: Even better: avoid SQL-injection entirely: `request <- sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), "SELECT data FROM database WHERE strip=?x", x = spread)`

Comment: It was me pressing enter by mistake, apologies. And thanks for your patience. I'm not very good at this yet :(